# Как посмотреть код программы написаной на C#

Tags: c#, exe

У меня есть exe файл который написан на С# и я хочу посмотреть исходний код  этого файла.

Comment: Никак не посмотреть.

Comment: Можно декомпилировать IL код, например с помощью ILSpy, он же на основе IL кода может сгенерировать C#, но посмотреть исходник так, как он был написан - не получится.

Comment: ILSpy на самом деле довольно неплохо восстанавливает, но не на 100%, одни конструкции он может заменить другими (возможно из-за того что так происходит компиляция), например я наблюдал, как ``else if`` меняется на ``switch-case``.

Answer (score 0):

Decompiler.NET 2005 или какой-нить Reflector

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]